# Can I log from a Laravel blade template?

Tags: php, laravel, logging, syslog

I want to log from within a Laravel blade template. Can I log something using the Laravel logger, or a simple `syslog(1, 'my message')` would even be better.

Comment: Sure. Just throw it inside of PHP tags. `<?php syslog(1, 'my message'); ?>`

Comment: or cant use `@php syslog(1, 'my message'); @endphp`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use logger in blade

```
{{ logger('Test') }}
```

Comment: How can I customize the format of the log - in this case?

Comment: Like, what If I want an "error", "warning" or "notice"? - do I have to issue an AJAX request in this case?

Comment: Hey @YuvalA.
You can use {{ info('Page visited') }},

Also alert|critical|error|warning|notice|info|debug instead of x {{ logs()->x('Page visited') }}

For example: {{ logs()->error('Page not found') }}

Answer (score 4):

You can use laravel helper function

for store information on log use `info` function

```
{{ info("print log in blade")}}
```

for debug level message on log use `logger` function
Don't add semi colon in the logger function.

```
 //{{ logger('Debug message'); }}

   {{ logger('Debug message') }}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also do below, especially in Laravel 4.2

[image]

And try to load that blade then view your laravel.log file

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a recent version of Laravel, use Telescope.
Link to Install Telescope: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/telescope

After installing telescope, use the following in any part of your blade file:

```php
Log::debug('Debug Message Goes Here'.)
```

[image: Laravel Telescope Screenshot]